# Problems with adding multiple sprites at different times using the Data Visualization Extension

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Everthing in this question works with just using the console in case you have the lastest viewer version (7.46), so if you want to try it yourself, is just a copy and paste to the console

Here's the problem, I want to insert sprites at different times, visually the next code works fine

```
      this.dataVizExtn = await viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.DataVisualization");
      this.DataVizCore =  Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core;

      this.style = new this.DataVizCore.ViewableStyle(this.DataVizCore.ViewableType.SPRITE, new THREE.Color(0xffffff), 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/16883010');

      this.viewableData = new this.DataVizCore.ViewableData();
      this.viewableData.spriteSize = 20; // Size in px
     
      this.worldPoint = {x:Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),y:Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),z:Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)};

      this.viewable = new this.DataVizCore.SpriteViewable(this.worldPoint, style, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000));

      this.viewableData.addViewable(viewable);
   
      await this.viewableData.finish();
      this.dataVizExtn.addViewables(this.viewableData);
```

The problem is that when I use the method [on the documentation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/handling_sprite_events/) to retrieve the information of the sprite, I get only the information of the last sprite added

```
      console.log(viewableData.viewables)
```

I know why this is, and is it because I'm creating again the viewableData variable every time I add a new sprite.

But making the change so I only declare it one time in the console

```
    this.dataVizExtn = await viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.DataVisualization");
    this.DataVizCore =  Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core;
    this.viewableData = new this.DataVizCore.ViewableData();
```

And then executing the new updated code multiple times without declaring again viewableData

```
          this.style = new this.DataVizCore.ViewableStyle(this.DataVizCore.ViewableType.SPRITE, new THREE.Color(0xffffff), 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/16883010');
    
          
          this.viewableData.spriteSize = 20; // Size in px
         
          this.worldPoint = {x:Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),y:Math.floor(Math.random() * 10),z:Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)};

          this.viewable = new this.DataVizCore.SpriteViewable(this.worldPoint, style, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000));
    
          this.viewableData.addViewable(viewable);
       
          await this.viewableData.finish();
          this.dataVizExtn.addViewables(this.viewableData);
```

Will make  console.log(viewableData.viewables) give back all the sprites inserted, but it will only paint in the viewer the first one

I'm not sure if this is a bug, since Data Visualization Extension was released less than 2 months ago, or if I'm doing something wrong

Edit: I have done something that seems like it fixes the problem, there are probably better solutions, but for now this seems to be working for me

```
    let oldViewableData = this.viewableData;
    this.viewableData = new this.DataVizCore.ViewableData();
    if(oldViewableData){
        this.dataVizExtn.removeAllViewables()
        for (let value of oldViewableData.viewables) {
            this.viewableData.addViewable(value);
        }
    }
```

And now it let's add new sprites to the already existing sprites, for now it seems like its working fine

Answer (score 1):

The second version of your code still doesn't seem correct because you repeatedly add the same `this.viewableData` object to the viewer whenever a new sprite (`viewable`) is added to this object.

The last snippet is probably what you'll want to do: only create a single instance of `ViewableData` and keep adding sprites/viewables to it whenever needed. And if you ever need to drop this object and create another instance of `ViewableData`, removing the original one using the `removeAllViewables` method you found is a good idea.